# Laravel - Write console output to log files

Tags: php, laravel

I have a command that outputs some lines:

```
/**
  * Execute the console command.
  *
  * @return mixed
  */
public function handle()
{
    $this->line('');
    $this->info('--------------------------------------------------------');
    $this->info('----------------- Compress documents -------------------');
    $this->info('--------------------------------------------------------');
    $this->line('');
    $progressBar = $this->output->createProgressBar(3);
    $this->info('Selecting files...');
    // ...
    $progressBar->advance();
    $this->info('Processing...');
    // ...
    $progressBar->advance();
    $this->info('Moving files...');
    // ...
    $progressBar->advance();
    $this->info('--------------------------------------------------------');
    $this->info('------------------------ Result ------------------------');
    $this->info('--------------------------------------------------------');
    // ...
    $this->info('Output quality: '.$resolution.'%');
    $this->info('Processed files: '.sizeof($files));
    $this->info('Original size: '.number_format($originalPathSize, 3).'MB');
    $this->info('Compressed size:'.number_format($compressedPathSize, 3).'MB');
    $this->info('Improvement: '.number_format($compressedPathSizeDiff, 3).'MB ('.number_format($compressedPathSizeDiffPercent, 3).'%)');
    $this->info('Total time: '.$timeFormatted);
    // ...
    $this->table($headers, $rows);
    $this->info('Ready!');
}
```

It works like a charm.

The problem is that now I need to run this command in a production server (via SSH) and it must take some hours to process all files. Obviously I don't want to stay logged in during this period to see console output.

As scheduling tasks does, there is some way to write "automatically" the console command output to log files?

Comment: Probably not, that I can think of, but you can add your own `Log::info()` lines to your code here

Comment: I'm also using lines like `$this->line('...');` which ARE being written to the laravel log files. Trying to figure out how this works.

Comment: @BramVerstraten `storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: @AlexandreThebaldi That's correct

Comment: @BramVerstraten Strange! my laravel.log stay intact after running the command many times...

Comment: I don't see anything in the [Command.php](https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/master/Command.php) that references the log, nor in the Console OutputInterface

Comment: Can you post your `config/logging.php` file?

Comment: @BramVerstraten Unfortunately my project doesn't have a `config/logging.php` :(

Comment: What if you take out the progress bar?

Comment: @BramVerstraten no effect! I think I should go with unix screen, as Vidal mentioned

Comment: It's a decent workaround, you only need to remember to add it to the command. I still want to know why the laravel logs are working for me though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `screen` linux command.
[Screen Example](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/)

and you can save the output like

```
#screen
#php artisan command > /etc/commandResults.log
```

Comment: Yep, the idea is that you want a command, and you should be able to execute it on the shell and get a result. If you change it to write always to a file it lost their purpose of having a command, using screen and redirecting you should be able to execute it without the connection issues. I was going to recommend a cron job but I was thinking it was not a recurrence need.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the `line()` method and implement this feature.
Add the option to write to log instead of console using an extra option in your command:

```
protected $signature = 'app:your-custom-command {--log}';


/**
 * Write a string as standard output or logs in laravel.log
 */
public function line($string, $style = null, $verbosity = null): void
{
    if ($this->option('log')) {
        logger()->log($style, $string);
    } else {
        parent::line($string, $style, $verbosity);
    }
}
```

Then make sure to define the `--log` in your `Kernel.php`.

```
$schedule->command(YourCustomCommand::class, ['--log' => true])->everyTenMinutes();
```

Just a headsup, this was a perfect solution for my usecase, but this solution would not display your table layout as it has its own rendering of `writeln`.

**Remark based on your initial thoughtprocess!**

You might want to dig into the posibilities to write output of scheduler job to email or file; see https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#task-output.

This might even solve your actual question of writing it to log instead of my suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

To write output to your logs from artisan commands you can simply call `$this->info()`:

`$this->info('some text');`

EDIT:

My bad! Sorry!

`Log::info()` is what you want.

Comment: The OP already is. That's most of the commands in their function. That command is only for [writing output to the console](https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan#writing-output)

Comment: False. I ran the command with `$this->info('...')` and it doesn't appears on log files